# VSCode Flutter popups

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image: VSCode Screenshot]

While typing I get two popups by my cursor. One is autofill suggestions I can interact with, and the other is just static textual information. How do I turn off the static textual popup?

I assume I can go into the settings, search for it, and toggle it, but I don't know what it is called to even google it. It appears specific to Flutter (or Dart) but I'm not positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to settings and then search for `editor.parameter hints` and then disable it

[image]

Comment: "Parameter Hints"! Wonderful...thank you Rohith.

Out of curiosity, what is the other popup referred to as?

Comment: Thank you, you can disable the auto suggestions by adding this line: `"editor.quickSuggestions": { "other": false, "comments": false, "strings": false },`